DCM Flyback Transformer Validation
I have designed a DC-DC flyback converter (DCM) of 30 W. To get the required output voltage of 13 V, I had to make my own custom transformer which could support the design requirements mentioned below. I have a custom transformer in hand, but I don't know how I can determine whether the transformer is as per specs or not, as it was manufactured by a local vendor. Can anyone help me on how I can evaluate the transformer?
Design Specifications:

Input Voltage: 50-150 VDC
Output Voltage : 13 V DC (Isolated)
Output Power: 30 W
Switching frequency: 75 kHz

I measured the inductance using LCR meter of the primary winding of the transformer, and it was 175 µH and by shorting the secondary and auxiliary windings and then measuring for leakage inductance, it showed (16.5 µH). To determine Nps, I applied a 75 kHz square wave of 12 V at the input, but it wasn't a proper square wave; rather, it was more like a pulse (see attached image below. Please don't mind the broken display of my DSO). Please let me know what other tests I can do to validate my transformer.


I have measured Inductance of the transformer by shorting the secondary and auxiliary windings, and it was correct (~175 uH). Are you sure about that? 175 uH of leakage seems a bit high to me, unless you have a sectioned bobbin.

Welcome! If you have an LCR meter, start by measuring the the magnitizing and leakage inductance. Those are critical parameters. The more tricky one will be the saturation current.

@RohatKılıç Thanks for the correction; it was a mistake from my end. I have edited my question again. Please feel free to let me know if there is anything else I'm missing in terms of testing.

@winny Thanks for your comment. I have measured both magnetizing and leakage inductance and it seems to be pretty good. Let me know what other tests i can do to validate it further.

Why not simulate your circuit with the transformer (as measured) and see how it performs?

16uH leakage out of 175uH magnetizing inductance still sounds rather high. What source impedance is your generator? The pulses seem to imply an L/R time constant around 300ns (if I'm reading that 3.3us/div scale correctly, and the frequency), implying either ~15uH for a 50Ω source or 580Ω for a 175uH primary. Perhaps you could try an LC (resonant circuit) test?

Can you make the voltage and current graphs across the primary winding?
